# Why does the compiler not give an error when making a "bad" cast?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

Consider following Java classes:

```
public class Animal {
    public static void printText(Object obj) {
        System.out.println(obj.toString());
    }
}

class Tiger extends Animal {
    // Contains some unimportant methods.
}
```

And now, when the following is typed into the main method, the compiler won't give any errors even though that cast will result in an error. Why?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal animal = new Animal();
    ((Tiger)animal).printText(animal);  // <= ?? no error in the compiler ??
}
```

Comment: Exceptions are thrown. Compiler errors are printed. Don't confuse yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, it might be easy to know that the cast is wrong - but in the general case it is not.

What if you had a method `Animal getRandomAnimal()` that might return `Tiger` as well. (Or the more common case, a method `Animal getAnimal()` that might be overriden by subclasses to return a `Tiger`).

At compile time, you could not possibly know if

```
Tiger tiger = (Tiger)getRandomAnimal();
```

is valid or not, **this is known only at run time**.

Answer (score 1):

Because in general, this cannot be detected at compile-time.  For example:

```
Animal a = (someCondition) ? new Animal() : new Tiger();

((Tiger)animal).printText(animal);
```